# Sort a dictionary key without in built functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to sort the given sentence according to length  in a sentence and store the length as key and the word as value. I want to sort this dictionary in a increasing order without using in-built functions.

The code I've tried:

```
    def string_leng(user_string):
    leng_dict = {}
    user_string = user_string.split(" ")
    for word in user_string:
        if len(word) in leng_dict:
            leng_dict[len(word)].append(word)
        else:
            leng_dict[len(word)] = [word]
    print(leng_dict)
    return leng_dict

def main():
    input_string = input("Enter sentence")
    string_leng(input_string)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output is as follows:

```
Enter sentencethis is a test test needs a check
{4: ['this', 'test', 'test'], 2: ['is'], 1: ['a', 'a'], 5: ['needs', 'check']}
```

The output I'm looking for is :

```
{5: ['needs', 'check'] , 4: ['this', 'test', 'test'], 2: ['is'], 1: ['a', 'a']}
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't semantically ordered data structures (although they do retain insertion order in newer Python versions). Also you can't have the same key twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly a dictionary needs have unique key values so your "looking to split each words" output, i.e.:

```
{5: ['needs'] , 5: ['check'] , 4: ['this'] , 4: ['test'], 4: ['test'], 2: ['is'], 1: ['a'], 1:['a']}
```

is not possible.

Regarding your initial desired output, in python3.6+ this is achievable with a slight modification to your current solution since dictionaries maintain insertion order:

```
def string_leng(user_string):
    leng_dict = {}
    user_string = user_string.split(" ")
    for word in user_string:
        if len(word) in leng_dict:
            leng_dict[len(word)].append(word)
        else:
            leng_dict[len(word)] = [word]
    res = {}
    for key in sorted(leng_dict.keys(), reverse=True):
      res[key] = leng_dict[key]
    return res
    # or equivalently using a dictionary comprehension
    # {k : leng_dict[k] for k in sorted(list(leng_dict.keys()), reverse=True)}

def main():
    input_string = input("Enter sentence: ")
    print(string_leng(input_string))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter sentence: this is a test test needs a check
{5: ['needs', 'check'], 4: ['this', 'test', 'test'], 2: ['is'], 1: ['a', 'a']}
```

---

**Alternate version that does not use the builtin `sorted` or `reverse` functions**

Feel free to replace the `quick_sort` or `reverse` functions with different implementations:

```
def quick_sort(a):
    left = []
    pivot_list = []
    right = []
    if len(a) > 1:
        pivot = a[0]
        for i in a:
            if i < pivot:
                left.append(i)
            elif i > pivot:
                right.append(i)
            else:
                pivot_list.append(i)
        left = quick_sort(left)
        right = quick_sort(right)
        return left + pivot_list + right
    return a

def reverse(a):
    list_length = len(a)
    for i in range(list_length // 2):
        a[i], a[list_length - 1 - i] = a[list_length - 1 - i], a[i]
    return a

def string_leng(user_string):
    leng_dict = {}
    user_string = user_string.split(" ")
    for word in user_string:
        if len(word) in leng_dict:
            leng_dict[len(word)].append(word)
        else:
            leng_dict[len(word)] = [word]
    res = {}
    for key in reverse(quick_sort(list(leng_dict.keys()))):
        res[key] = leng_dict[key]
    return res
    # or equivalently using a dictionary comprehension
    # return {k : leng_dict[k] for k in reverse(quick_sort(list(leng_dict.keys())))}

def main():
    input_string = input("Enter sentence: ")
    print(string_leng(input_string))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I can't use a built in function like sorted and reversed.

Comment: You can, it's easy! Or do you mean you are not allowed to?

Comment: Yes not allowed to.

Comment: @Newbie I added a version that does not use the built in functions of sorted and reversed.

Comment: @ShashSinha Thankyou I've been trying with quick sort as well. Can you explain in brief what does reverse function here help in?

Comment: Your desired output has the keys in the order: 5, 4, 2, 1. Without the reverse the `res` dictionary would have the keys in the order: 1, 2, 4, 5. I.e, `{1: ['a', 'a'], 2: ['is'], 4: ['this', 'test', 'test'], 5: ['needs', 'check']}`

Comment: @ShashSinha Okay yes got it. Thankyou!

Comment: @ShashSinha For {'r': 1, 'e': 3, 's': 1} I try to interchange the value and key format. While modifying the current code by getting values instead of keys, it doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: @Newbie The value 1 appear's twice. Remember keys must be unique in dictionaries/hashmaps.

Comment: @ShashSinha Keys are unique here, values can be different. I want to sort according to the value now.

Comment: If you post another question I can fix it for you. I would rather fix your code then write a solution from scratch. Basically you need to sort the key-value tuples (by the value) and then insert the key value pair in that order.